# android get firebase notification when has a new entry

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

in my android i am developing a function when user searches a email id in a database. if the particular email id found..then a friend request should be sent to that email id.
1) when user enters a email id, it searches in firebase database/users/... user info...

if child with that email id found, then i am getting his userid...
till now i am done with this.

now i have a function name as sendrequest as follows

```
 DatabaseReference
 db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notification/"
 + receiver+"/"+fcount); Map<String,Object> t=new HashMap<>(); t.put("sender",""); t.put("receiver",""); t.put("type","friend
 request"); t.put("status","not friend");//not friend -friend- unfriend
 db.updateChildren(t)    
         .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
             @Override
             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Friend request Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }
         })
         .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
             @Override
             public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                 //dismiss wait dialog here====================
                 //false to add friend=====================
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error while sending friend request",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });
```

but the question is i want to implement a service... through which... the particular receiver will get notification when the new entry is added to the database in  notification/receiver ...means only the particular receiver should get notification.

i am new to firebase, i only know about how to implement CURD operations in firebase db..

please someone help.

Comment: To target individual device, you will need to store the  firebase token id generated for device in your server / db. If the condition to receive message for a user meets, you will retrieve this tokenId for the user and send notification to that tokenId.

Comment: will you please elaborate? how can i achieve this. also please tell me.. about notification

Comment: you can follow this tutorial at https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/firebase/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial . It has all the details you need.

Comment: thanx for sharing a link... i will try it...and will let you know

Comment: i havnt tried it yet. i will try it tomorrow. but now i have just go through it... but its the tutorial to send notification from firebase console. but i want to send notification. when their a new entry under notification node. with the user id as its child. then the user with that uid only will get notification

Comment: the notification should be trigger automatically on new entry added

Comment: You did not go through the tutorial. Read it entirely and you will see where the token id is generated and there is even comment on a method to tell you what to save in db. Read It.